# Maybe PHP eval scope thing?

Tags: php, eval

I'm having an issue with the following code. I'm just guessing it's a scope problem.

```
public function run() {

    return eval('$this->config();');
    // This will return null.

    return $this->config();
    // This will return my config array right.

}
```

Before anyone asks:

1. Not both return are 'active' when testing.
2. I know eval is evil, but i'm building some kind of terminal for admins to run PHP code.

Do anyone have any suggestions about this terminal thing? (My basic problem is still with the eval...)

Comment: try this return eval('return $this->config();');

Comment: Eval is evil, I've got to say it again.

Comment: also, in addition to eval being evil, building some kind of terminal for admins to run PHP code is *really* evil.

Comment: (`eval` isn't "evil". Evil is a moral judgement that is far too often liberally applied. Now, it might be misguided and/or not appropriate and/or a bad practice and/or ..)

Comment: Wilson, you're solution was right.

Comment: @pst I think we're implying here to the act of using eval in the context of programming, which can be considered evil towards the future maintainers of the code, as well as towards the programmer himself or the client having the software.

Comment: @eis Again, that is a moral judgement. It is no more appropriate to use "evil" to describe `eval` than it is to use "gay" as a derogatory term. It is a "fun" term, but it misses out the actual *reasons* why eval should be avoided. Now, `eval` could be using in an evil manner, by a malicious "hacker" programmer wishing to cause harm to another person .. (note that in this last sentence I impose a moral judgement; it is the actions of said programmer which I am judging.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`eval`](http://php.net/eval) is returning NULL because that is what it is suppose to do. Right from [the documentation page](http://php.net/eval):

> `eval()` returns NULL unless `return` is called in the evaluated code, in which case the value passed to `return` is returned.

Comment: and also, from the same page: "The code will be executed in the scope of the code calling eval()", so there should be no scoping issue.

Comment: Yep, i misunderstood... i tought if my config() method has return, but i've found it elsewhere the solution. Anyway thanks guys!